# how load data correctely with template ngIF

Tags: angular

I want ot show a text based on the value of my data :

- if data is **not set** I want to show "wait"
- if data is **empty** here I want to show "ok"
- if data is **not empty** here I want to show "occupé"

This is my template(is in a loop ):

```html
<ul>
    <li class="heure" *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche" [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==false" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
          occupé
        </a>
        <li class="heure" *ngFor="heure.unavailable=false" [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==true" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
               ok
        </a>
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==0" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
            wait ...
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModel } from '../calendar-model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SemaineComponent } from '../semaine/semaine.component';
import { CalendarService } from '../calendar.service';

@Injectable()

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heure',
  templateUrl: './heure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heure.component.css']
})

export class HeureComponent implements OnInit {

  parTranche: number = 3600; //par tranche d'une heure 3600 seconde
  trancheDeb: number = 8;//la journée commence à 8H
  trancheFin: number = 17;//la journée se termine à 17H

  plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;
  plageHeure = new Array();// = this._semaine.courrantSemaine; si elle est vide pas d'affichage avec ngIf != 0

  debJ0H;//sauvegarde le jour J

  constructor(private _calendar: CalendarModel, private _semaine: SemaineComponent, private _calendarService: CalendarService) {
    this.debJ0H = this._semaine.courrantSemaine[this._semaine.iBoucle];
  //  this.plageHeure.push({ "afficheH": this.trancheDeb, "unavailable": false });
```

My firt attempt was to test that `plageHeure` is an empty array, but I have an parsing error :

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 19 in
>   [heure.unavailable=false] in ng:///AppModule/HeureComponent.html@5:26
>   ("
>                 occupé
>               
>               ]*ngFor="heure.unavailable=false" [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
>               <"): ng:///AppModule/HeureComponent.html@5:26
>       Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 19 in [heure.unavailable=false] in ng:///AppModule/HeureComponent.html@5:26
>   ("
>                 occupé

How can I make my tamplate to work correctly?

thank's for help

Comment: In the code you posted you have `*ngIf="heure.unavailable==false"`, but the error says `"heure.unavailable=false"`, which one are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for reply, this is my template when i test simple tempate:

```html
<ul>
    ** test template ** 

    <!-- 

            <li class="heure" *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche" [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==false" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
          occupé
        </a>
    
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==true" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
               ok
        </a>
        <a  *ngIf="heure.unavailable==0" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
            wait ...
        </a>
    </li>
    -->

</ul>
```

[image]